# Painted content invisible while resizing in Java

Tags: java, graphics, resize, window, minimize

**Please note I haven't tested this on a Windows-machine only on a Mac-machine. I'm not so sure whether this also occurs on a Windows-machine...**

When I resize my Java-application the content is invisible. I already found a way to fix it *after* resizing it, but not *while* the user is resizing the window.

I'm not using Swing or something because it makes my binary so slow (in my opinion).

The structure is like this:

- **`Frame`** My main-window
- - **`Containe`r** Content view of *`main-window`*
- - - **`Container`**-based subviews that including the `paint(Graphics g)`-method

I've added all listeners to *`My main-window`* and now I'm able to redraw the *Content-view* **after** resizing the window.

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    this.contentView.paint(this.contentView.getGraphics());
}
```

I am beware of the fact using the `paint(getGraphics())`-method isn't a really good way to do this, but since the `repaint()`-method doesn't do anything at all, it's the only working possibility.

While resizing, all painted content becomes invisible. However, when I add a `Button`-instance to my *`Content-view`* and resize my *`Main-window`*, the button doesn't get invisible.

I *am* able to trace the 'live'-resize event:

```
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Live-resize");
}
```

1. When I start resizing this method is not being called.
2. While resizing it generates "Live-resize" in my log every single pixel I resize the window.
3. When I stop resizing this method is not being called, the componentResized-method does.

When I add my repaint-method (or the official repaint-method) to the 'live'-resize event like this, I still get the output, however, it's not repainting or something

```
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Live-resize");
    this.contentView.paint(this.contentView.getGraphics());
}
```

Or

```
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Live-resize");
    this.contentView.repaint();
}
```

When I minimize my application to the dock and maximize the application again, the same thing happens, I guess that the same code is needed to fix this.

I'm not using `Graphics2D` or something, just `Graphics`.

Could you please explain me how I can repaint the views?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: See also "Painting in AWT and Swing" http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html

Comment: Consider posting Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (SSCCE) that demonstrates the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I would suggest investigating why you think Swing makes your application so slow instead of trying to work around that limitation with AWT components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally fixed it.

Instead of redrawing it every time in the `paint(Graphics g)`-method, you need to buffer the output and only redraw that image (I kinda hoped Java would be already doing that, just like Obj-C).

```
public BufferedImage buffer;

public void redraw() {
    buffer = new BufferedImage(
            200, // height
            300, // width
            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR); // ABGR = RGBA, 4-byte (r, g, b, a) per pixel
    Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
    // do your drawing here
    if (this.getGraphics()) {
        // 'this' is already shown, so it needs a redraw
        this.paint(this.getGraphics()); // little hack
    }
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    this.paint(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Now, when you minimize the window and maximize it again, the paintings remain. Only, the window's flickering now for .1-second or so, but I don't really care about that.

Comment: I think there's still more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 7):

For reference, here is the same program using Swing. Because `JPanel` is double buffered, it doesn't flicker as the mouse is released after resizing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new CirclePanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final Random r = new Random();

        public CirclePanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
            this.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt()));
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    CirclePanel.this.update();
                }
            });
        }

        public void update() {
            this.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt()));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Dimension size = this.getSize();
            int d = Math.min(size.width, size.height) - 10;
            int x = (size.width - d) / 2;
            int y = (size.height - d) / 2;
            g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawOval(x, y, d, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858355/230513) on aspect ratio.

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score 5):

I'm more familiar with Swing, but the article [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) distinguishes between system- and application-triggered painting. The example below shows how the system invokes `paint()` as the window is resized, while the application invokes `repaint()`, which calls `update()`, in response to a mouse event. The behavior is cross-platform.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class AWTPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.add(new CirclePanel());
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class CirclePanel extends Panel {

        private static final Random r = new Random();

        public CirclePanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
            this.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt()));
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    CirclePanel.this.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            this.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt()));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Dimension size = this.getSize();
            int d = Math.min(size.width, size.height) - 10;
            int x = (size.width - d) / 2;
            int y = (size.height - d) / 2;
            g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawOval(x, y, d, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?