# Drawing 2Dcircle in an Jinternal frame

Tags: java

I have a JInternal Frame and I want to draw a circle(using 2Dgraphics) in it and make it flexible. I mean when I change the size of frame the circle become smaller or in making frame larger circle also become larger. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

You would draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel or JComponent that is held in the JInternalFrame's contentPane, same as you would draw in any other JPanel. I'd get the dimensions of the JPanel at the start of the paintComponent method and use those values to tell how big to draw the circle.

Also, if you add the JPanel directly to the JInternalFrame's contentPane, it will be added by default BorderLayout.CENTER, and so when the JInternalFrame changes size, the JPanel also changes size, it's paintComponent will be called by the JVM, and the new drawing will be resized automatically.

Comment: +1 Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538082/painted-content-invisible-while-resizing-in-java/3538279#3538279).

Comment: Thanks for example. It is great!

Answer (score 0):

add a `WindowListener` to the jInteralFrame and redraw whenever the size changes

Comment: No need for a window listener if you're drawing in a component that is held say BorderLayout.CENTER in the JInternalFrame.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels well i thought that would be obvious and he was talking about manually drawing it with a Graphics object on a canvas or something