# Any way to resize my components on my Java Game?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, graphics, components

I've made a concentration-pairs game using netbeans.More details for the game here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game) .

before the game starts the user has the ability to choose the game version (computer vs human,human vs human),their names and the memory of cards that computer has to remember in a computer vs human version,and also to choose dimensions and jokers.He can choose a specified size and jokers or his own preferred sizes (columns,rows,jokers).
Of course i have a limit for row and columns : 52.But playing with setResizable doesn't help at all when the user uses eg 52x52 or 50x3 as dimensions for the game... it looks horrible (Btw the images are 73x97 pixels).

My components are not buttons they are objects of my own gui class concerning cards (and has a connection with the logic of the card from another package).So i should try gridbaglayout instead of gridlayout? Gridbadlayout can be a real headache cause i've already used it for my radiobuttons.

right now i am using gridlayout but when i had setEnabled(true) so the eg 10 rows would actually fit on screen,the graphic card would stay small and not "fill" the whole component...

http://postimg.org/gallery/53g9ag0i/667f8271/ What i mean here

Should i resize all my components or the limit is too big and i should make it smaller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridLayout` is usually fine when you want components that have all the same dimensions. I recommend simply putting your grid of cards inside a `JScrollPane`.

Alternatively, if having the game area scrollable when the grid dimensions are large is unacceptable, you can take a look at the answer to this question: [How to lock aspect ratio of a gridLayout in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857537/how-to-lock-aspect-ratio-of-a-gridlayout-in-java).

Yet another possibility is extending `GridLayout` so that it tries to keep fixed aspect ratio for the cards. (For this you obviously need cards that are capable of drawing themselves properly at different sizes).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you compute the best size? Calculate what the maximum value for cards in a row is. Then estimate the minimal icon size of a card so that anybody can read it. Then you just have to calculate: ScreenDimensions / mininmalCardSize. And then you can adjust the desired size from the user. This is how i would do it. But i would like to use the Null Layout.