# Flashing while reloading JTree

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jtree, double-buffering

I am making a simulator with a `JTree` updating frequently. The nodes in the tree are all `JProgressBars`.

I'm calling `tree.treeModel.insertNodeInto(,,)` and `treeModel.reload()` to update the tree. the problem is that it instantly updates itself without waiting for a `repaint()` call. This causes the tree to flash. I have tried setting `setDoubleBuffered(true)` for the nodes, the tree, and the containers it is in, but nothing changes.

Here's my code: (The class `File extends DefaultMutableTreeNode`)

```
public class FileTree extends JTree {

    DefaultTreeModel myTreeModel;

    FileTree(File root) {
        super(root);
        myTreeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) this.getModel();
        this.treeModel = myTreeModel;
        this.setCellRenderer(new ProgressBarCellRenderer());
        this.setEditable(true);
    }

    public void update(File file, File parent) {
        myTreeModel.insertNodeInto(file, parent, parent.getChildCount());
        myTreeModel.reload();
    }

    class ProgressBarCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            File file = (File) value;
            JProgressBar progressBar;
            progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, file.length);
            progressBar.setValue(file.completed);
            progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(Math.log(file.size)*50),10));
            return progressBar;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you [*mixing heavy and light components*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/)?

Comment: Maybe. but I don't care about performance a lot, because the overall rate of update is small enough. I just want to get rid of the flash/blinking when reloading happens. A buffer should do this. But I don't know how to do it in a simple way.

Comment: There is no need to call `reload()` after `insertNodeInto`. `insertNodeInto` internally calls `fireTreeNodesInserted` which in turn updates the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just changed

```
myTreeModel.insertNodeInto(file, parent, parent.getChildCount());
```

to

```
parent.add(file);
```

I don't know why it works now. But it does. Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: parent.add(file) breaks model-based update logic - you add new components only into view and need manually update UI.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that [mixing heavy and light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) is causing the flashing. The effect can be seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538251/230513) by clicking on the circle or resizing the enclosing frame. For better guidance, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for sscce. I'd have done it. But it seems too much work, since the problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same trouble with custom renderer.

Just make updates inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTreeModel.insertNodeInto(file, parent, parent.getChildCount());
        }
```