# Force fixed width-to-height ratio in Swing window

Tags: java, swing, resize, window

I've searched for this question but didn't really find a clear, helpful answer. I'm building my first Java UI apps<sup>1</sup> (using Swing) and I was wondering one thing: how can I force the resizing of windows to happen scaled? It's something aesthetically important for my upcoming program. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks! And guys, I'm not asking for 'just give me a solution', I KNOW you guys hate that, I just need someone helping me reach it!

1. It's a little Boggle game. I have a grid with `JButton` instances to simulate the dices of Boggle (these need to be clicked to form words), and when I resize the window I want the dices to keep being square, they get rectangular and that's not really how it should be.

Comment: "how can I force the resizing of windows to happen scaled?"... I'm not sure what your asking for here. Do you mean to maintain the frame's width-to-height ratio if the user resizes it?

Comment: @splungebob Exactly that yeah! The width-to-height ratio should stay the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for component resized events on your window and set the desired scaled height when the width is changed.

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
  public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // TODO: calculate new size and set it
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However, you will have to tweak this such as you avoid flickering.

Comment: How would I be able to avoid flickering?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to adapt the approach shown in `JDigit`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513), which resamples a large `BufferedImage` to fill the component; resize the frame to see the effect. You can enforce the 1:1 aspect ratio by setting the `width` and `height` to the same value: `Math.min(width, height)`. A related example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538279/230513).

[image]