# Component won't display unless window is resized - Java

Tags: java, image, swing, resize, components

I have problem with image visibility after click the button. I have the main class with frame:

```
package superworld;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class SuperWorld {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(1050,650);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
       frame.add(new SuperPanel());
       frame.setVisible(true);
    //   frame.setResizable(false);
    }

}
```

Then I have class with Panel with all components:

```
package superworld;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SuperPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        Timer mainTimer;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 550;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1050;
        int i;
        int w=-100;
        int h=-50;
        ArrayList<SuperMiasto> miasta = new ArrayList<SuperMiasto>();

   private JButton heroButton;
   private JButton cywilButton;


    public SuperPanel() {
        mainTimer = new Timer(10,this);
               heroButton = new HeroButton(this);
               cywilButton = new CywilButton(this);
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);                           
                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    miasta.add( new SuperMiasto() );
                    miasta.get(i).x=w;
                    miasta.get(i).y=h;
                    miasta.get(i).imagelabel = new JLabel(miasta.get(i).image);
                    miasta.get(i).imagelabel.setBounds(miasta.get(i).x,miasta.get(i).y,miasta.get(i).image.getIconWidth(),miasta.get(i).image.getIconHeight());
                    add(miasta.get(i).imagelabel);
                    w=w+200;
                    if (w > WIDTH-200)
                    {
                        h=h+200;
                        w=-100;
                    }
                }

    }
      public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
           add(heroButton); 
           add(cywilButton);               
    }   
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
    }
}
```

And Class with button with add new object with image:

```
package superworld;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class HeroButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    HeroButton(JPanel buttonPanel) {
        super("Dodaj hero");
        this.buttonPanel = buttonPanel;
                setBounds(0,500,150,50);
        addActionListener(this);              
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SuperLudzie batman = new SuperLudzie();
            batman.imagelabel = new JLabel(batman.image);
            batman.imagelabel.setBounds(50,50,batman.image.getIconWidth(),batman.image.getIconHeight());
        buttonPanel.add(batman.imagelabel);                
    }
}
```

And class of this SuperLudzie:

```
package superworld;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SuperLudzie {
    private String imie;
    private int zycie;
    private int inteligencja;
    private int wytrzymalosc;
    private int sila; 
    private int umiejetnosci_walki;
    private int x,y;
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Zuzanna Sawala/Moje dokumenty/NetBeansProjects/SuperWorld/mysz.jpg");
    JLabel imagelabel;
}
```

Everything work great. I have only problem with this object and image created by button it's not visible just after clicking but after i resize a window. I know that it have something to do with setVisibility(true); but i'm not sure where to use it.

Comment: Use a layout manager

Comment: Yes, use a layout manager, and prior to your frame.setVisible(), try a frame.pack().

Comment: But in future i want my objects to move and show on random places so i wanted to use setLayout(null);. Which Layout i should use?

Comment: *"i want my objects to move and show on random places"* Use custom painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

Use overridden `paintComponent()` method instead of `paint()`

```
class SuperPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
}
```

[Read more points...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340271/why-doesnt-the-ball-show-up-in-the-frame-if-i-add-the-ball-after-the-for-loop/24340286#24340286)

Try to avoid `null` layout and use proper layout that suits as per our need.

Please have a look at [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) that has sole responsibilities for positioning and sizing of the components.

Comment: @Vekka: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027550/230513).